# sample asp program to select all the checkbox while selecting one checkbox from the check box list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im new to ASP. can any body give the sample code for select all the checkbox while selecting one checkbox from the check box list.

Select All

A

B

C

once checking the select all check from the checkbox list all other items also should get selected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _Give me sample code_ is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: You are using Jquery?

Comment: if you are referring to client side - then use JQuery to find all elements in the list and check them. However since you have not provided any code... I therefore won't provide any code either.

Comment: You say you are new to ASP but you tag Asp.Net...?
What are you looking for classic Asp or Asp.Net..?

Answer (score 0):

First off, Please try to search internet for answers, since you are new to ASP, its better to try examples from the internet.--> [Link to W3](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_examples.asp)

what you can try is on click of "select all" check box, iterate through the checkbox collection list, and set the selected property to true.

Something like this

```
foreach (ListItem item in this.CheckBoxes.Items)
{
   item.Selected = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `jquery` for this purpose , use this id `input#chkView` for the main `checkbox` that will select/deselect all checkboxes and assign this class `.viewPerm` to all the `checkboxes` that you want to to check/uncheck on click of `input#chkView` .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input#chkView').change(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                $('.viewPerm > input:checkbox').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('checked', true);
                });
            }
            else {
                $('.viewPerm > input:checkbox').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('checked', false);
                });
            }
        });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

take a one checkboxlist add item, add first item text as Select All ,after creating checkbox, set autopostback property to true, and handle selectedindexchanged event of checkboxlist
use following code in in the selectedindexchaged event:

```
        if (CheckBoxList1.Items[0].Selected == true)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = true;
            }
        }
```